# A way to flow content into columns automatically?

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I am looking for a way to flow content into the next column automatically when it detects the height is not enough to content the elements.

I know this can be done in CSS3 with columns, but sadly IE users will not be able to use it.

Is there another way that I am missing via CSS?

For a pseudo code:

I have 400px height container with list elements within and the list elements are not fixed height as some lists have more content than others.  When the list elements total height goes beyond 400px, it will just be hidden.  Instead, I would like it to flow to the next column over and continue top to bottom again...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a polyfill to support IE and still use CSS3 columns.

Here is a [huge list of HTML5 polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills), and the [CSS3 - Multi Column Layout polyfill](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/) should fix your issue.